# Weil Conjectures - Is the Artin-Hasse Zeta Function an Euler Characteristic in some sense?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

In an earlier answer regarding the Weil Conjectures - Motivation, Thom Tyrell replies "One very incredible thing about the Weil Conjectures is what they say about the geometry of a smooth, projective variety XX defined over ℚQ (for example); some of the geometry of XX as a complex manifold can be computed by counting points on XX modulo pp for some (suitable) prime. Specifically, the Weil Conjectures allow you to compute the Betti numbers (dimensions of vector spaces coming from cohomology) of X/ℂX/C by computing the Zeta function of X/pX/Fp."

Is there a direct way to obtain the zeta function from a (Weil?) cohomology, as an Euler characteristic and further interpret the Weil zeros (Jacobi sums/convolutions) maybe as (discrete) Hodge periods? Any further explanations or references will be appreciated.

Comment: Just adding a reference to that earlier answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/253612/127490

Comment: What's a "direct way"? You can recover the genus by using the functional equation. About periods, for curves, I think that the $2g$ roots of $f(t)$ in  $Z (X_0, t) = f(t)/ ((1 - qt)(1-t))$ may codify the jacobian of $X_0$, but I'm not sure.